# is there a less bloated way to test constraints in grails?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, constraints

Is there a less bloated way to test constraints? It seems to me that this is too much code to test constraints.

```
class BlogPostTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {

    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        mockDomain BlogPost
    }

    void testConstraints() {
        BlogPost blogPost = new BlogPost(title: "", text: "")
        assertFalse blogPost.validate()
        assertEquals 2, blogPost.errors.getErrorCount()
        assertEquals "blank", blogPost.errors.getFieldError("title").getCode()
        assertEquals "blank", blogPost.errors.getFieldError("text").getCode()

        blogPost = new BlogPost(title: "title", text: ObjectMother.bigText(2001))
        assertFalse blogPost.validate()
        assertEquals 1, blogPost.errors.getErrorCount()
        assertEquals "maxSize.exceeded", blogPost.errors.getFieldError("text").getCode()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advise against testing `getErrorCount()`, as you'll make your tests fragile (as you add other constraints, you'll have to remember to update every instance of `new BlogPost()` anywhere in your test cases). Just check `hasErrors()`.

Other than that... for each constraint, you need to generate some test data that violates it, call the validation routine, and assert on the errors. This is the code you need.

Refactor out some methods to remove the duplication. example:

```
private void assertConstraintWorks(clazz, fieldName, testData, expectedErrorCode) {
    def instance = clazz.newInstance((fieldName): testData)
    assertFalse instance.validate()
    assertTrue instance.hasErrors()
    assertEquals expectedErrorCode, instance.errors?.getFieldError(fieldName)?.code
}

void testConstraints() {
    assertConstraintWorks BlogPost, 'title', '', 'blank'
    assertConstraintWorks BlogPost, 'text', '', 'blank'
    assertConstraintWorks BlogPost, 'text', ObjectMother.bigText(2001), 'maxSize.exceeded'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ross Niemi, a coworker of mine, created the [Domain Expectations plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/domain-expectations) which uses a nice DSL for exercising and validating constraints on grails domain objects.  We use it at my work place, and I've been very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you want to hear, but: Do you really want to test the constraints defined in your domain model? In essence, what you are doing here is testing the validation framework of Grails rather than your own code. Don't get me wrong, tests are necessary (especially with dynamic languages like Groovy), but IMHO one shouldn't just blindly test everything that comes across. Maybe I'm just not too much of an hardcore TDD guy, but I just don't see the point here.

Comment: Daniel, that's exactly what I was thinking. I mean, when a method performs some kind of an algorithm which changes some kind of state, it makes sense to write a unit test as a kind of "don't care how you do it, but get it done" test: it confirms the effects of the algorithm.

With constraints, there is absolutely no black box and apparently no value in unit testing. To be honest, I would love to see at least one convincing example of writing unit tests for constraints, if for no other reason, than because I'd love to use the seemingly elegant built-in testing framework. ;)

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question and instead is just a debate/discussion point.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/04/unit-testing-constraints-in-domain.html) has a good description of unit testing constraints. One thing I didn't see above is the use of mockForConstraintsTests() (which eliminates need for mockDomain())

And to comment on Daniel, yes I would test the constraints defined in my domain model to assert that I have correctly constrained the domain model. You make a typo in a constraint declaration and you won't find it until an integration or functional test (and in the meantime will drive you nuts)